# Laravel Controller Error - Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class FormContoller extends Controller
{
  public function add(){
  $item = new App\Item;
  //Some random code with the $item class
  return redirect('success');
  }
}
```

Here's my Routes.php

```
Route::post('add','FormController@add');
```

Also, the controller has the name - "FormController". No errors there, I guess.

But, I get the following error...

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 776:
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\FormController does not exist

I'm beginner. Please help out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that controller in the folder `./controllers/http/` and if so, shouldn't the namespace be `App\Controllers\Http`?

Comment: The controller folder is in Http - app/Http/Controllers.
Laravel 5 directory structure changes I guess. I haven't used Laravel 4.

Answer (score 2):

You've called if `FormContoller` but in `Routes.php` it says `FormController` - with two r's.

Cheers,

Comment: Ouch.. absolutely! Thanks a lot. Was so frustrated.. Thanks a lot!